# UILabel and UITextField edit character

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I m doing a anagram type of task in iOS. In this case i need a solution,

For ex:

```
NSString* quest = @"SATCK";
labelQuestion.text = quest;
```

I have a UITextField to type the answer. The correct answer is "STACK". The user will type this to the UITextFiled. For ex: When the user types "S" in the textfield i need to remove the character "S" from the UILabel, similarly if he deletes the character "S" in textField I need to bring back the "S" in UILabel. This should happen for all the characters user types.
If the user types "STACK" in textField i need to hide S, T, A, C, K characters from the UILabel one by one. HOw can I achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a delegate object that conforms to the "`UITextFieldDelegate`" protocol.

Then you can catch characters being typed into your text field via [`[UITextFieldDelegate textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a).

In that method in your delegate object, you can write code to detect what characters are being typed in and you can subtract those letters from your label (or re-add them if the characters were deleted from the text field).